# why the value of hashCode is same while all are different String Object

Tags: java

Why the value of hashCode is same while all are different String Object:

```
public class StringObj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1="Jack";

        String s2=new String("Jack");

        String s3=new String("Jack");

        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());

        System.out.println(s2.hashCode());

        System.out.println(s3.hashCode());

  }

}
```

Comment: [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()): **If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.**

Comment: In case of String object, hashCode is based on content. In case of other custom Objects,  hashCode is based on m/m address.

Answer (score 5):

The Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for Object says that if an object `equals()` another, it must have the same `hashCode()`. This makes sense, since both objects are, supposedly, representing the same thing.

From a practical standpoint, this is very important. It allows you to use a well known String to write into and read from a map instead of having to use a singleton object key.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

The contract of [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) explicitly say that the `hashcode()` of the two objects should be the same if `equals` returns `true` for them.

Note that equals on these strings will return `true`. So **it is necessary** that the `hashCode` is the same.

---

**Long Answer**

The [contract of hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) says:

> The general contract of hashCode is:

- > Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer,  provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the object is  modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution
  >   of an application to another execution of the same application.
- > If
  >   two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
  >   calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce
  >   the same integer result.
- > It is not required that if two objects are
  >   unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling
  >   the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct
  >   integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that
  >   producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the
  >   performance of hash tables.

[`hashCode` of String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) is computed as:

> `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`
>
> using `int` arithmetic, where `s[i]` is the `i`th character of the
>   string, `n` is the length of the string, and `^` indicates
>   exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

so, THE `hashCode()` of `String` uses the value of the `String` to compute the `hashCode`. Many objects do that. So as long as the content is the same, the `hashCode` will be the same. This is specifically because that is what the `hashCode` contract mandates.